# execute Java applet as big as possible without losing proportions

Tags: html, jar, height, width, distortion

following code displays a java applet in a html page.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
if (_ie == true) 
    document.writeln('<OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" WIDTH = "100%" HEIGHT = "100%" NAME = "WebClientX" ALIGN = "middle" VSPACE = "0" HSPACE = "0"  codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,6,0,0"><NO EMBED><XMP>');
else if (_ns == true) 
    document.writeln('<EMBED type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"  CODE = "webclientx.Applet1" ARCHIVE = "WebClientX.jar" CODEBASE = "." NAME = "WebClientX" WIDTH = "100%" HEIGHT = "100%" ALIGN = "middle" VSPACE = "0" HSPACE = "0" ServerName =  "" Synoptic = "Hauptansicht" ServerPort =  "12233" UserName =  "" Password =  "" Protocol =  "0" Compress =  "false" Encrypt =  "false" Sealing =  "0" Timeout =  "60000" ShowMenu = "false" MouseMotion = "true" MouseClicks = "true" KeyEvents = "true" ShowStatusBar = "true" PlaySoundOnAlarm = "true" scriptable=false pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp"><NO EMBED><XMP>');
//--></SCRIPT> 
... 
...
...
```

i have two options:

1. define a fixed size
2. make it as big as possible (applet gets steched/distorted on wide screen monitors)

i would need a third option: the applet should be as big as possible but without beeing distorted.

is this possible?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the `width` attribute altogether and just leave it as `<applet ... height="100%" ... />`? At least on images this scales the width accordingly.

Comment: doesnt work.. distorts it even more.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by placing the above code inside a DIV, setting the size in the above code to 100%, and then updating the div size every second according to videwportsize.